# Migration to change default value for a field and change all existing record's value to new default value only if it has old default value.

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I need to change the default value of a field from 0 to 3, but the catch is i have thousands of records already and want those records to change the value to 3 from 0 only if the record has default value 0 but for other values like 1, 2 it should remain the same. how can i do it?

Comment: Can't you just 'UPDATE table SET value = 3 WHERE value = 0'?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

In the migration you should use the method change_column to alter the table settings like this:

```
change_column :my_models, :attribute_name, :integer, :default => 3
```

And then to update all existing records, instead of looping through all records and updating them individually you could use the method update_all like this:

```
MyModel.update_all({ :attribute_name => 3 }, { :attribute_name => 0 })
```

The first argument tells the method what value to set and the second tells it the condition for which rows to update.

Comment: I'm wondering if this might only work on certain databases as I'm not sure all will allow the default value to be changed. Anyway, I can confirm it works on MySQL.

Comment: I just tried this, and I think the syntax might have changed. This worked for me: `MyModel.update_all({:attribute_name => 3}, {:attribute_name => 0})`

Comment: update_all in Rails 4: Model.where("status=0").update_all(status: 2)

Comment: @DanneManne thank you Danne is it possible to add this within the migration file itself?

Comment: @BKSpurgeon Sure, that is possible. However, there are a few things worth considering if you do this. The first is how to handle this between migrations and rollbacks. The easy answer is to not place this code in a `change` block, but instead manually define both `up` and `down` in the migration and only call `update_all` inside the `up` method. The second thing is slightly more long term, and that is what happens if you end up removing the model all together at a later time? In that case you are left with a migration that uses a model that doesn't exist. Just something to think about.

Answer (score 2):

```
ALTER TABLE your_table MODIFY your_column tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 3;
UPDATE your_table SET your_column=3 WHERE your_column=0;
```

1. assuming your column is `tinyint(1)`, replace your self if not the same
2. `NOT NULL` is assuming you always force the column to be  `NOT NULl`