# Migration file updated not reflect in Schema.rb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am running a migration like this:

```
class CreatePages < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :pages do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :permalink
      t.integer :position
      t.boolean :visible

      t.timestamps
  end
end
end
```

And then I figure I forgot to set the default value for the boolean, so I go back to the migration file and add the following:

```
t.boolean :visible, :default => false
```

I then run the rake db:migrate again. However, the schema.rb file does not update. I had run the migration before for quite awhile so it is not possible to rollback and redo the migration. 
I know that I should not update the Schema file directly. 
Anyone can help me to make the schema.rb file to update according to what I have change in the migration file.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add new migration to change default value for the column.

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7021620/migration-to-change-default-value-for-a-field-and-change-all-existing-records-v)

Comment: Is there a way I can edit the old migration file without adding a new migration?

Comment: No, You have to write a new migration or rollback previous migration, then edit & re-run migration.